# Как подстроку из одной строки вставить в другую строку на определенное место?

Tags: php

Есть 2 строки:

```
http://site.com/dir/
../img/image.jpg
```

Подстроку img ищу регулярным выражением.
Как сделать перестановку. чтобы получилось

```
http://site.com/img/dir/
```

Comment: `parse_url` сделайте и в `path` потом в начало добавьте

Comment: Это можно решить одной строкой, с помощью preg_replace(). Если до вечера никто не поможет, я напишу ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно решить одной строкой, с помощью preg_replace():

```
$string = 'http://site.com/dir/';

$replace = 'img';

$string = preg_replace('~https?://[^/]+\K(/)~', "$1$replace$1", $string);

echo $string;
```

Результат:

```
http://site.com/img/dir/
```

Comment: В принципе можно `https?` откинуть вообще, `://` сразу дает понять, что это ссылка)